# R Shiny - how to generate this layout with nested rows in column 2

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I'd like to have two rows under "Fluid9" and this isn't working. The first row should have three plots whereas the second row should only have 1 plot spanning the width (9) of the 3 plots in the first row. What am I missing?

I'm trying to get something like [this](http://shinyprognostics.de/pemDemo/) layout (see 2nd image below), except that i don't need the sliders on the left side.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
      "Fluid12",
         fluidRow(
           column(3,
             "Fluid3",
             numericInput('H_lbv', 'Height - lower bound', 10),
             numericInput('H_ubv', 'Height - upper bound', 21),
             numericInput('D_lbv', 'Diam. - lower bound', 8),
             numericInput('D_ubv', 'Diam. - upper bound', 16),
             numericInput('ro_lbv', 'Dens. - lower bound', 0.3),
             numericInput('ro_ubv', 'Dens. - upper bound', 1.0)
             ),
           column(width = 9,
               "Fluid9",
               fluidRow(
                       column(3,
                              plotOutput("plot")),
                       column(width=3,
                              plotOutput("plot2")),
                       column(width=3,
                              plotOutput("plot3"))
               ), fluidRow( ## I thought this would work to add the second row
                       column(width=9,
                              plotOutput("plot3"))
               )
           )
         )  
      )
  )
 )
)
```

Server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {    

        xseq <- reactive({
                x1 <- input$H_lbv - (input$H_ubv - input$H_lbv)/2 # set my x-axis left bound
                x2 <- input$H_ubv + (input$H_ubv - input$H_lbv)/2 # set my x-axis right bound
                # return
                seq(x1, x2, 0.01)
        })

        densities <- reactive({
                dpar <- get.norm.par(p = c(lb, ub), q = c(input$H_lbv, input$H_ubv), plot = FALSE)
                mean <- dpar[1]
                sd <- dpar[2]
                # return
                dnorm(xseq1, mean, sd)
        })        
        densities2 <- reactive({
                dpar2 <- get.norm.par(p = c(lb, ub), q = c(input$D_lbv, input$D_ubv), plot = FALSE)
                mean2 <- dpar2[1]
                sd2 <- dpar2[2]
                # return
                dnorm(xseq2, mean2, sd2)
        })        
        densities3 <- reactive({
                dpar3 <- get.norm.par(p = c(lb, ub), q = c(input$ro_lbv, input$ro_ubv), plot = FALSE)
                mean3 <- dpar3[1]
                sd3 <- dpar3[2]
                # return
                dnorm(xseq3, mean3, sd3)              
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
                plot(xseq1, densities(),
                     col = "darkgreen", xlab="", ylab="Density", type="l",lwd=2, cex=2,
                     main="Height", cex.axis=.8)
        })
        output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
                plot(xseq2, densities2(),
                     col = "darkgreen", xlab="", ylab="Density", type="l",lwd=2, cex=2,
                     main="Diameter", cex.axis=.8)
        })
        output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
                plot(xseq3, densities3(),
                     col = "darkgreen", xlab="", ylab="Density", type="l",lwd=2, cex=2,
                     main="Packing Density", cex.axis=.8)
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your new fluidRow, the new max width becomes 12 (it's always nested). So you need to change the width of the three columns from width = 3 to width = 4, and change the last column from width = 9 to width = 12.

```
       column(width = 9,
           "Fluid9",
           fluidRow(
                   column(width=4,
                          plotOutput("plot")),
                   column(width=4,
                          plotOutput("plot2")),
                   column(width=4,
                          plotOutput("plot3"))
           ), fluidRow( ## I thought this would work to add the second row
                   column(width=12,
                          plotOutput("plot3"))
           )
       )
     )  
  )
```

Comment: i did not realize that. However, smg is still missing as the plots are still not showing up (i.e. no change from my first image).

Comment: If your plots are not rendering, it might be related. There are a couple of things that could be the case:

1. You have two plotOutput("plot3"). You can only call them once.
2. There is no plot4. I'm assuming there should be?
3. You might want to re-structure your fluidRows & columns for better layout.

I think taking out the last plot3 should do the trick.

Comment: Correct (per my previous comment). Whenever you create a plot in server and call it in ui, it creates an ID for it. That ID is the plot name. (So #plot1, #plot2 etc). On HTML pages, you can only call IDs once. Do it more than once and you start breaking things. It's not a shiny thing, but rather a web development thing.

Comment: repeating the plot was the problem! I fixed it by generating my 4th plot. Thanks I learnt a few things!